# Can someone tell me what a resx key is in terms of .Net applications

Tags: .net, key, resx

This is a question that was asked by one of the leading CMS companies about their product and I am not sure what they mean by this.

Do you have a resx key - GoBack and resx file for ContentViewSingleItem.ascx

Can someone maybe tell me what a resx key is?

Thanks

Comment: What was the context of the conversation? If it was failing to load, are you sure they didn't say licx? that being a license key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the key with which you can obtain a value from a resource (.resx) file. This is used in the context of localization where, depending on the culture, the application gets the value from the correct resource.

To read more about it take a look at [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx).